# Creating an audio player that is persistent cross pages.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, audio

Alright I am sure this has been asked one billion times on this website but what could another ask hurt and plus I am looking for some advice I have yet to find.

I am working on creating an audio player and I want it to be able to work with MP3's using some ajax functions to stay on pages as you browse the website. The only problem I am having with this is the fact that with ajax it manually does not load any other pages for me other than the index page where the audio is being displayed for this example. So I was wondering how I would go about only refreshing the page while the audio player stays persistent.

If any of these currently exist on the internet and you know of them please include links I am beyond interested in this.

Also would it be possible to use iFrame around the audio player for this?